# Why is <textpath> not showing up?

Tags: svg, polygon

Expected behavior:

[image]

I'm trying to write ABC in polygon with the help of  but nothing is showing up. Is this the right way to do?

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" viewBox="0 0 84 96">
    <g id="ABC" transform="translate(-8.000000, -2.000000)">
      <g transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
        <text x="10" y="100" style={{ fill: '#64FFDA' }}>
          <textPath href="#Shape" fill="#64FFDA">
            ABC
          </textPath>
        </text>
        <polygon
          id="Shape"
          stroke="#64FFDA"
          strokeWidth="5"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          fillOpacity="transparent"
          points="39 0 0 22 0 67 39 90 78 68 78 23"></polygon>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: xlinkhref is missing a : between xlink and href

Comment: `textPath` received `href ` and not `xlinkhref`. checkout the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

Comment: Also y="100" is way off the canvas.

Comment: I tried replacing with `href` but still not able to see any text. Also it gives me compilation error if I use `xlink:href`

Comment: If you just want to write "ABC" inside the polygon - why do you need the textPath? Do you understand what's the value of this?

Comment: I'm new to svg. As of now, I just needed to write 'ABC' inside the polygon. When I tried to look up this issue online I found out one way to do is through `<textPath>` . So I opted for this way.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to do? What could be the reason my text not showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to place letters inside the polygon, you need to place the `<text>` command below the `<polygon>` command
Pay attention to the syntax of SVG command writing. Instead of `strokeWidth ="5"` you need `stroke-width ="5"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" width="20%" height="20%" viewBox="0 0 84 96">
<g id="ABC" transform="translate(-8.000000, -2.000000)">
  <g transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
    
    <polygon
      id="Shape"
      stroke="#64FFDA"
      stroke-width="4"
      fill="#151515"
      points="39 0 0 22 0 67 39 90 78 68 78 23"></polygon>
  </g>
  <text x="50" y="55" font-size="22px" font-weight="500" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#64FFDA" text-anchor="middle" >ABC</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```